# What different between canActivate and canLoad in ionic

Tags: router, ionic5

I'm using **auth** in ionic-5 and i have two options when write auth in route `canActivate` and `canLoad`
example  :

```
   {
        path: 'login',
        loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginPageModule',
        canLoad: [AuthGuard],
        canActivate [AuthGuard]
    },
```

But what the difference between `canActivate` and `canLoad` and when i should  use each one !

Comment: I think this has been answered many times and angular's documentation is pretty clear: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39664364/canload-vs-canactivate-for-lazyloading/40536862 Is there something specific you are not getting from those answers?

Comment: Not an Ionic question. This is Angular